# Change color of whole app - for every item outlet necessary?

Tags: swift, storyboard, assets, uicolor

I have a color set in the assets catalog and I used this color now for all my buttons, labels, switches, image backgrounds and so on.
I want to create now the ability for the user, to select it's own color (by using a color picker) for the whole app.

As far as I have googled now, I understand that it is not simply possible to change the assets color, I have to create a color and store this in the `UserDefaults` and load this color every time the `viewDidLoad`.

The question is now, because I am using `storyboard` to create all my buttons, switches and so on, do I have to create for every single item an `outlet` to change the color?

Or is there a better approach to handle this?

Comment: You need not have `IBOutlet` for all your UIControls instead you can use `UIView`'s `UIAppearance` property to set the various properties like background color or tint color for example `UIView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.red UIView.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.green` but there is a catch with `UIAppearance`

Comment: quoting apple docs "iOS applies appearance changes when a view enters a window, it doesn’t change the appearance of a view that’s already in a window. To change the appearance of a view that’s currently in a window, remove the view from the view hierarchy and then put it back."

Comment: basically when user changes the color, pop the view controller and reload the `ViewController` that should ensure that all the components which are subclass of `UIView` in that VC will now reflect the background and tint color you set, if you are wondering where to put those statements in `ViewController` put it in `ViewDidLoad`

Comment: Thank you for your information. Unfortunately that doesn't work for me. I've tried the settings backgroundColor and tintColor, but then it changed of course ALL backgroundColors and tintColors. On some buttons I need the background to change, on some buttons I need the tint to change...

Comment: Do you need color change on the all the instance of some specific button class ? If yes you can add your custom property to `UIAppearance` that way when you set the property only the instance of that specific class will have its color reflected other instances wont

Comment: i have for example a button which I just have a background color, but if I change the color with UIButton.appearance().backgroundColor ALL buttons are in this color. I have also some buttons where the background is just "transparent" and the foreground color is the color I want to change.